# What is wrong with my homstead.yaml file in laravel5

Tags: virtualbox, laravel-5

I am trying to install laravel 5 in windows but when i run homestead up command it show a time out while waiting for the machine to boot error. Below is my code

```
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 1
provider: virtualbox

authorize: C:\Users\DB\.ssh\id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - C:\Users\DB\.ssh\id_rsa

folders:
    - map: C:\bin\tmp\yahavi
      to: /home/vagrant/Code

sites:
    - map: homestead.app
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/Laravel/public

databases:
    - homestead

variables:
    - key: APP_ENV
      value: local
```

My project folder directory is C:\bin\tmp\project

Answer (score 0):

The most likely explanation for this is that you do not have the virtualisation settings enabled in your machine BIOS. I appreciate that this sounds unlikely, but I experienced the same problem with a newly built desktop last week. If you have an intel machine enabling VT-X in your machine BIOS or the equivalent on an AMD machine fixes this issue.